# why disarm error doesn't give error object in rebol?

Tags: rebol

```
rebol []

secretAgent: do func[ /local person firstName lastName][
  firstName: "James"
  lastName: "Bond"
  person: make object! [
    whoAreYou: func[][
      print rejoin ["My name is " lastName ", " firstName " " lastName]
    ]
  ]
]

secretAgent/whoAreYou
if (error? (error: try [secretAgent/firstName])) [
  probe disarm error
]

input
```

returns

```
My name is Bond, James Bond
** Script Error: Invalid path value: firstName
** Near: secretAgent/firstName
```

whereas I would expect same result as for

```
probe disarm try [secretAgent/firstName]
input
```

which returns:

```
My name is Bond, James Bond
make object! [
    code: 311
    type: 'script
    id: 'invalid-path
    arg1: 'firstName
    arg2: none
    arg3: none
    near: [secretAgent/firstName]
    where: none
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try without the extra (parentheses)

```
if error? error: try [secretAgent/firstName] [
  probe disarm error
]
```

REBOL 2 errors are hair trigger. Your error was triggered in bubbling up one set of parentheses, rather than trapped.

See the difference here:

```
if error?  error: try [0 / 0]  [print ['bad mold disarm error]]
if error? (error: try [0 / 0]) [print ['bad mold disarm error]]
```

REBOL 3 error handling is slightly different -- **disarm** is not longer necessary, for example.

Comment: Yes the () should not make any difference. But REBOL2 is just a little too sensitive. REBOL3 gets it right: the extra () makes no difference.

Comment: () cause an evaluation when they are used within an expression. which is why the error is triggered, since the error wasn't disarmed.

Answer (score 9):

Ah, that's a good example of why R3 tones down the way errors get triggered.

In R2, when an ERROR! values is evaluated (processed by the interpreter) it will activate the error handling mechanism. So, if you're not really careful, as you pass around the error value (like passing it to a function, returning it as a result, or in your case, evaluating it within a paren expression), it's going to trigger the error exception handler again.

In retrospect, this hair trigger was a poor evaluation rule. So, that's why **R3 no longer handles errors that way**. But, we cannot change it in R2.